# What´s the role or function of the homologous arms in a donor template in a knockout/knock edition via Crispr-cas9?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, crispr, cas9

I have to make an exposition in my university about Crispr-cas9 edition and I have some questions about the method. In the knock out/knock in technique is used a plasmid containing the DNA that codifies for the Cas9 protein and guideRNA and a **Donor template** that has a gene for puromicine resistance, and a DNA that codifies for a fluorescent protein and **"left homologous arm" and "right homologous arms"**. My questions is What's the fuction of the homologous arms?Furthermore what's the role of the Loxp(look at the image)?
The method is described here   http://www.origene.com/assets/documents/CRISPR-CAS9/CRISPR_manual.pdf   (page 5-10)[image]

Comment: This is not the CrispR/Cas9 system but the LoxP system which works differently.

Comment: It is there to facilitate homologous recombination and thereby a knock-in. See http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/29735/3340

Comment: @ Chris This plasmid can be part of the CRISPR based knock outs, the LoxP sites are there to recycle the marker if you want to do successive knock outs